# Microsoft.WebApplication.targets was not found MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to setup CI on my website.

I've built a Psake script (following a course on PluralSight) that handles the build and packaging ... etc.

I am getting this error when I **locally** run my build script.

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct and that the file exists on disk.
>   Done Building Project "C:\code\bejebeje\BB.WEB\BB.WEB.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Why is this happening? Inside of VS 2017, the solution is building fine without any errors!

Comment: That targets file is part of Visual Studio. Do you have VS installed on the CI machine?

Comment: Well, so far I'm running the script locally. And locally, I do have VS2017 installed